# Stackoverflow calls I am in risk of being banned - after long time when I was silent

Tags: support

I was busy elsewhere long time (about six months or more) and when I wanted to ask new question, StackOverflow calls I am in risk of being banned.

Why now? Why not before that long time? Did I something wrong?

Comment: The warnings have been implemented in that timeframe, e.g. you could have been close 6 months ago but there were no warnings being given then.

Comment: The warning was implemented in May of last year. I don't know for how long you've been gone, but that might be it.

Comment: @Bart: last post on April 29th 2014, unless there is a deleted post that is newer.

Comment: Ahh, that it may be - because from May I was busy elsewhere (in my work I got that time - and then I had not a time for programming).

Comment: Also note that it's possible for various actions (votes, votes to close, deletion, etc.) may have been taken on your posts during that time, potentially resulting in the system being concerned about your quality now, despite no recent posts.

Comment: It almost seems silly that that didn't even occur to me, @Servy! heh

Answer (score 6):

This was your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381028/php-html-how-to-keep-data-in-html-code-but-hidden-from-user-without-html5-at

It's closed, deleted, and scores -7. That's not particularly encouraging. So when the system sees your last question looking like that, it tries to give you a warning. Just in case you were planning on posting another one that would end up the same way.

For more details, see: [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118)

Answer (score 1):

Your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381028/php-html-how-to-keep-data-in-html-code-but-hidden-from-user-without-html5-at) (now deleted), was asked in April of last year. As [Bart notes above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281805/stackoverflow-calls-i-am-in-risk-of-being-banned-after-long-time-when-i-was-si/281806#comment137547_281805), we've since then implemented the warnings.

If you are just getting a *warning*, you should be OK as long as you take care to ask quality questions.

Comment: All changes are also listed [in this Meta Stack Exchange thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), leading to a date of May 6th for this particular change.